# Set default permissions for files within directory of mounted S3 Bucket

Tags: amazon-s3

I have an S3 bucket mounted on my server.  It was mounted as root.

I need to make all files within certain folders within the bucket owned by another user by default because when I try to perform operations on that directory as that user, it says access denied.

I tried:

```
sudo setfacl -Rdm u:newuser:rwx /path/to/directory/
```

I also unmounted the bucket, then logged in as that user and tried to remount it, but because that user didn't have access to the password file it didn't work either.

Do I have to just give that user permissions on the password file?

Is there any other way to do this?  Open to any other solutions.

Comment: How are you mounting S3 as a drive? Amazon S3 is an object storage system, not a filesystem. Any such permissions would be associated with the method/software you used to mount S3. It is not a recommended method for accessing content on S3.

Comment: Mounted using fuse

Comment: It would be better to use Amazon EFS to mount a filesystem rather than using Amazon S3 with `fuse`.